# Sorting a 2 Dim array in C

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort a 2d array based on the value of the first element per row. So, the row which at the first position of the array has the lowest value should be put at the beginning of the array.

The code that I m using below:

```
int Array[5][4] = {
{8  ,1  ,1  ,0},
{6  ,0  ,0  ,0},    
{7  ,1  ,1  ,1},
{2  ,1  ,1  ,1},
{1  ,1  ,1  ,1} };

void sortArray(int Sort[][4])  
{   
 int k=0,x,temp;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(Sort[i][k] > Sort[j][k])
            {
                for(int x=0;x<2;x++) 
                {
                    temp=Sort[i][x];
                    Sort[i][x]=Sort[j][x];
                    Sort[j][x]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }


 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        printf("%d ", Sort[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
 }
}
```

The output I want:

```
1  ,1  ,1  ,1
2  ,1  ,1  ,1
6  ,0  ,0  ,0
7  ,1  ,1  ,1
8  ,1  ,1  ,0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to choose whether you want a C solution (e.g. `qsort`) or a C++ solution (e.g. `std::sort`). Your title says C, your tag says C++. Which is it?

Comment: Please clarify, if you search a solution in C or C++. The title indicates C, but the tag says C++. Chose one.  Can you also provide the current output?  By the way, your array seems already to be sorted by initialization, right?

Comment: Well, from the content of the question, it seems he wants to sort the 2D array in *ascending* order based on the first element in each row.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: He said that the highest value should be at the beginning, which means descending for me.

Comment: I know what he said -- but then look at ***"The output I want:"***.

Comment: By the way: It's a bad style to assume that the first dimension of `int Sort[ ] [4]` has a size of 5. This makes your code less portable and more error-prone to further changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
```

You are only swapping the first two elements of each row, not all four. The following change should make it work as intended:

```
for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
```

Comment: works, thanks! So the swap is based on the number of the columns

Comment: You are swapping **rows**, so you have to swap all elements in each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life simpler by using a `std::vector<std::vectror<int>>`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Array = { {8  ,1  ,1  ,0},
                                        {6  ,0  ,0  ,0},    
                                        {7  ,1  ,1  ,1},
                                        {2  ,1  ,1  ,1},
                                        {1  ,1  ,1  ,1} };
```

Then you can use `std::sort` and lambda function to sort them.

```
std::sort(Array.begin(), Array.end(),
          [](std::vector<int> const& lhs, std::vector<int> const& rhs)
          { return lhs[0] < rhs[0] });
```

---

If the array sizes are known at compile time, use of `std::array` is also a possibility.

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 4>> Array = { {8  ,1  ,1  ,0},
                                          {6  ,0  ,0  ,0},    
                                          {7  ,1  ,1  ,1},
                                          {2  ,1  ,1  ,1},
                                          {1  ,1  ,1  ,1} };
```

or

```
std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 5> Array = { {8  ,1  ,1  ,0},
                                            {6  ,0  ,0  ,0},    
                                            {7  ,1  ,1  ,1},
                                            {2  ,1  ,1  ,1},
                                            {1  ,1  ,1  ,1} };
```

`std::sort` can be used either of those arrays.

---

If you must use a 2D array, it's going be bit more involved since arrays cannot assigned. You can create an array of pointers that point to the elements of `Array`, sort the array of pointers using `std::sort`.

```
int Array[5][4] = {
{8  ,1  ,1  ,0},
{6  ,0  ,0  ,0},    
{7  ,1  ,1  ,1},
{2  ,1  ,1  ,1},
{1  ,1  ,1  ,1} };

int* ptrArray[5] = {Array[0], Array[1]. Array[2], Array[3], Array[4]);
std::sort(ptrArray, ptrArray+5, 
          [](int* lhs, int* rhs)
          { return lhs[0] < rhs[0] });
```

After that the sorted array can be accessed using `ptrArray` even though `Array` still remains in its original state.

Comment: OP asked for a solution in C. Your answer is for C++.

Comment: @sebrockm, It's tagged C++.

Comment: sorry, you are right. OP, could you clarify by either changing the tag or the title?

Comment: nested `std::vector` for such a small structure? I would rather suggest `std::vector<std::array<int,4>>` or even `std::array<std::array<int,4>,5>`

Comment: @PeterT, those are also possible. It depends on whether the sizes of the arrays are known at compile time.